# Postgres - CHAR isn't blank-padded?

Tags: string, postgresql, replace, char

According to the Postgres documentation:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html CHAR data type is blank-padded to the required size. I don't understand why the second query doesn't return the same output as the first one.

```
-- output "aaaxxxxxxx"
SELECT REPLACE('aaa       ', ' ', 'x');
        
DROP TABLE test;
CREATE TABLE test (
col1 CHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO test(col1) VALUES ('aaa');

-- REPLACE output "aaa"
SELECT col1, REPLACE(col1, ' ', 'x')
FROM test;
```

In Oracle and Sql Server both SELECT return the same output. Why is different in Postgres?

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of the `replace()` function is of data type `text`, so your `char` input is implicitly cast to `text`. This makes it lose its trailing blanks.

The behavior may be different from other database systems because that's how we implemented it. `replace()` is not described by the SQL standard. PostgreSQL's behavior matches other weirdnesses that the SQL standard describes for `char`, like that it loses its trailing blanks upon string concatenation.

The [PostgreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Text_storage) explicitly warns you not to use `char`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved. It's worth to mention that only OCTET_LENGTH see spaces. I assume that the reason is the same as you said, but interestingly all the function in Postgres docs has input paremeter specification as STRING(whatever it is).
SELECT col1, REPLACE(col1, ' ', 'x'), LENGTH(col1), CHAR_LENGTH(col1), OCTET_LENGTH(col1)
    FROM test;

Comment: That's probably because `octet_length()` is not defined in the standard, so PostgreSQL can choose a more logical implementation.